# Fan not working on motherboard even if same voltage works with batteries

Tags: voltage, current, basic, cases

First of all I want to mention that I have no knowledge electrical field, so please forgive me if I will not be explicitly enough or I lack some terms, but I know no one with knowledge about electricity and spend a lot of time trying to figure out what is going on using google.

- I bought a **5V/100mA fan** for my **Odroix XU4Q single board computer**.
  *(full fan specs: http://noctua.at/en/nf-a4x20-5v/specification)*
- When I connect it to 2 pins socket on Odroid XU4Q board, **fan is not working**. That socket is supposed to 
  provide **5V/200mA** and it is designed for and sold along with a CPU
  **fan of 5V/120mA**

  *(full CPU fan specs: http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G146727436639 )*

  *(full Odroid specs: https://dn.odroid.com/5422/ODROID-XU4/Schematics/XU4_MAIN_REV0.1_20151202_LOT1606.pdf , page 4 for FAN)*
- If I connect ground(black) and voltage(red) to USB or 3 x AAA 1.5V
  batteries, fan is working.
- I measured **voltage on the board**, but it seems fine. On 100%
  load, voltage **is ~4.10V**
  *(fan intensity is based on voltage which is controlled by cpu temperature)*
- I measured the **3 x AAA batteries** and it is the same voltage: **~4.10V**.
- **Current** while fan is mounted on batteries is oscillating pretty much, **between 15mA to 65mA**, but tends to stay more around 60mA
- **Current** with fan mounted to the board, it is almost 0. I am assuming electricity is not going through my fan's circuit.
- mounted the fan to the USB port of the same Odroid board and stressed CPU to 100% load to consume as much power as it can. Fan still starts. Measured voltage in USB port is ~4.90V
- added 1 AAA battery in series with the board to create higher voltage,
  which measured ~5.25V (black wire coming from the board went into "+" of the battery and another wire from the "-" of the battery went to the fan black wire input). Fan not starting.

**So, what I know:**

- I=E/R (I=current, E=voltage, R=resistance)
- R should be the same (because same circuit is used: fan, cables)
- Voltage is the same

**What I don't get it:**

- Why the current is 0 if ***E*** and ***R*** are the same between batteries use and board use?!
- What may be the problem?
- What do you suggest me to do/check?

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: The problem seems to be that the temperature never gets high enough to switch on the fan. The 4.1 V you measure at the fan connector with no load drops to 0 when you plug in the fan, but you know the fan isn't too heavy a load. You're seeing 4.1 V behind some high impedance - a peculiarity of the fan driver. Also, don't just "stress CPU to 100% load" - warm the board (with a hair dryer perhaps). I think your question *is* on-topic: maybe no one has reviewed your edits yet.

Comment: sensors on the board shows a temperature of 80 degr. Celsius when CPU is stressed to 100% load.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but noctua do discuss [Polarities.](http://noctua.at/en/nf-a4x20-5v)

> **Polarity protection**
>
> As many devices using 5V fans feature proprietary connectors and documentation of the pin alignment may not be available, the fan features an integrated diode for polarity protection. This way, you're on the safe side if you accidentally connect it with reverse polarity.

It would explain your observed:

> Current with fan mounted to the board, it is almost 0. I am assuming electricity is not going through my fan's circuit.

Comment: I think it would explain if I reversed the polarity, but I didn't. Voltage measured was +4.10V, not -4.10V. Anyhow I tried both ways and didn't start. On USB or batteries, it is starting only if you mount it in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Odroix XU4Q is the fanless version of the Odroix XU4. So the 3 things to check are:

1. Is the fan connector enabled? Check for a voltage on the fan connector.
2. Is the fan connector only enabled when temperatures are high? Not all fans are always on.
3. Is the fan connector even an option in the code/linux/kernel for this model of the board? It's not meant to run with a fan.

Comment: 1. Fan coonector is enabled. As mentioned, I measured voltage with DMM. In 100% load for all 8 cores, voltage is around 4.10V on the board connector of Odroid XU4Q.
2. Voltage increase as the temperature increase. I am not sure when it should start, but I am pretty sure it should run when CPU is 100% load.
3. There should be no differences between XU4Q and XU4. You can buy XU4Q and put the fan they sell or reverse. There is no different OS version for XU4Q compared to XU4.

Comment: @softwareRat it wasn't clear if you measured the fan connector or the normal power. In that case, if you connect the fan and spin it manually, does it start spinning by itself? If so, then the board isn't providing the current needed to start the fan. Check with an oscilloscope, is it PWM?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "normal power". I put DMM sticks on the 2 pins of the Odroid board while CPU was in 100% load and measured the voltage "DCV". It doesn't start if I spin it manually. It is not PWM. I do not own an oscilloscope and I am not sure what I need to measure or who may help me with this ( I rather prefer to return the fan and buy the smaller version which has max input current 50mA instead of 100mA)

Comment: According to the schematics, the fan is PWM. See sheet 4 of 33.

Comment: Normal power input = the DC Barrel power input to the board. The Fan connector is not the same thing as the power input.

Comment: @Passerby power input into the Odroid board is 5.23V

Comment: @Tyler I am not sure you are right, because there is another fan 5V 40mm wide and 20mm thick which is called nf-a4x20-5v-pwm (http://noctua.at/en/nf-a4x20-5v-pwm). But I own this: http://noctua.at/en/nf-a4x20-5v.

Comment: About lack of enough power or higher resistance of the fan. I used USB port when CPU is 100% loaded (to consume as much power as it can) and fan starts on USB port of the same Odroid board. So what is wrong with that 2 pin socket?!

Comment: How did you connect the 3 pin fan to the 2 pin socket, and what did you do with the 3rd pin?

Comment: Fan has 3 colored cables: red, black, and yellow. I connected black cable from the fan on the "ground" pin in the board and red cable from the fan on the voltage pin in the board (voltage measured on those pins was ~ +4.10V, so I didn't reversed polarity); 3rd pin is not connected to anything; the same wiring works with batteries;